# Reading CSV file with proper encoding in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I can not read the csv file in my jupiternotebook, the following is the link github link of the csv file

```
https://github.com/roshanthokchom/new-assignment/blob/master/spam.csv

 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
 import urllib
 pd.read_csv('spam.csv',encoding='latin-1')

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 13, saw 4
```

Comment: Welcome to stack.. it looks like you file is tab separated, by default `read_csv` is thinking that your file is comma separated. Can you try `pd.read_csv('spam.csv', sep = '\t')`

Comment: @DataPsycho  is right or rather you can use  pd.read_table('spam.csv', encoding='latin-1') its default it take tab as seperator

Comment: Edit the post - add [Solved] to the title and in the contents how it was solved.

Answer (score -1):

@Roshan here is the solution to your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
with open('spam.csv', newline='') as f:
    csvread = csv.reader(f)
    raw_data = list(csvread)

data = []
for i in batch_data:
    i = i[0].split("\t")
    data.append(i)

final_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You can specify encoding as you have done but your file consists of commas in between text so if you read normally pandas will separate data based on ",". Thats why you are getting an error

Comment: You do not need to `open` the file separately to read it in to pandas actually when it is a small amount of data. So I do not suggest that approach.

Comment: @DataPsycho I thought he is having problem parsing the data. because of the error, I suggested the solution, also sep= "\t" caused inconsistency in my dataset many time.